# How do i connect two views in an RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an RCP application, in which I want to connect 2 views so that when I click a node of `TreeViewer` in view1 the `TableViewer` in view2 must be populated.

[image: Screenshot of my application]

I have 2 view classes namely `ViewPart1(TreeViewer)` and `ViewPart2(TableViewer)`.
Can anyone help me out in achieving this?

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP (using the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point)?

Comment: Ths is a 3.x compatability application

Comment: Use the [Selection Service](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html)

Comment: Thanks @greg-449...I tried with selection service but nothing is happening. Can you provide a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selection service.

In the view (view1) which is providing the selection you must set the selection provider to be the tree:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

where `viewer` is a `TreeViewer` (or `TableViewer`) or something else that implements `ISelectionProvider`.

In the view which wants to see selections set up a listener:

```
ISelectionService selService = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();

selService.addSelectionListener(listener);
```

where `listener` is something that implements `ISelectionListener`.

Note: Your listener will be told about selection changes everywhere, it is up to you to sort out which ones you want to react to.